# save rdd of array of array to text file spark

Tags: arrays, list, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD called tmp like this.

```
"org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, String, Double)])]"
```

and the values are like as below.

```
Array[(String, List[(String, String, Double)])] = Array((1076486,List((1076486,1076486,0.0), (1076486,431000,0.7438727490345501), (1076486,351632,3.139055446043724), (1076486,431611,6.173095256463185))), (430067,List((430067,430067,0.0), (430067,1037380,4.0390818750047535), (430067,431611,6.396930255172381), (430067,824889,7.265222659014164))))
```

and my output should be the inner contents of the list like below...

```
1076486,1076486,0.0
1076486,431000,0.7438727490345501
.
.
430067,1037380,4.0390818750047535
```

I tried this..

```
.mapValues(_.toList).saveAsTextFile
```

It appears as below in the file.

```
(1076486,List((1076486,1076486,0.0), (1076486,431000,0.7438727490345501), (1076486,351632,3.139055446043724), (1076486,431611,6.173095256463185)))
(430067,List((430067,430067,0.0), (430067,1037380,4.0390818750047535), (430067,431611,6.396930255172381), (430067,824889,7.265222659014164)))
```

I could print the desired data by below code

```
tmp.collect().foreach(a=> {a.foreach(e=>print(e+" "))})
```

But cannot save it to the file.

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create output strings manually:

```
tmp.values.flatMap(_.map{case (x, y, z) => s"$x,$y,$z"})
```

Comment: Thanks zero323. You rock !!